# 'Invalid hdr' error when exporting Batch Payment (Export Scenario process)

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

I am trying to create an export scenario, but I get an 'invalid hdr' error when i try to 'Export' the Batch Payment.

the screenshot for the error is as follows:
[image: batch payment error]

I do not know why this error occur or what it means.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?  I have the same issue.  It looks like the Provider.GetBatchNbr() is not getting the correct value for the batch.  I have copied/pasted the Export AP Payment to ACH v2 export scenario but, to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

The error suggest something wrong with your export scenario. Carefully look for any mistakes in fieldnames and/or expressions.